# Project dependency diagram in Visio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dependencies, visio

I'm looking for a tool that will generate an assembly/project dependency diagram in Visio (or as close as possible) to assist me with breaking up some of our system into more manageable trunks.

The ability to include/exclude non-project dependencies is a must (i.e. include/exclude System. assemblies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ReSharper.  (I'm not associated with the product or company, but it provides many nice features for dependency walking).

You can also try the Depends.exe with the SysInternal toolset - now from Microsoft.

[ReSharper by jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Answer (score 0):

Visio has the ability to reverse engineer UML from your solution.  You can find more information [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/HP815507451033.aspx).  It's not clear to me whether you can include the .Net assemblies, however -- since they are not really in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

UML Class template/shapes should be helpful here, you can use the "package" object and connect the relationships with a number of lines to choose from